# AngularJS ng-grid clumping together grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm trying to do a basic `ng-grid`. I have it is defined and it has data. I'll attach a picture too, I haven't ever seen ng-grid do this, but this is the first time I'm setting it up myself so maybe I'm doing it wrong. Here's my code:

My Controller:

```
    controllers.controller('searchResultsController', ['$scope', '$rootScope',
    function($scope, $rootScope) {

        $scope.data = $scope.searchResults.data || $rootScope.searchResults.data;
        $scope.resultsGridOptions = {
            data: 'data',
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    field: 'startingCity',
                    displayName: 'Starting City',
                    width: '***'
                },
                {
                    field: 'destination',
                    displayName: 'Destination',
                    width: '***'
                },
                {
                    field: 'airline',
                    displayName: 'Airline',
                    width: '**'
                },
                {
                    field: 'price',
                    displayName: 'Price',
                    width: '*'
                },
                {
                    field: 'seatsInFirstClass',
                    displayName: 'Seats In First Class',
                    width: '*'
                },
                {
                    field: 'seatsInEconomy',
                    displayName: 'Seats In Economy',
                    width: '*'
                }
            ]
        };
    }
]
);
```

My app declaration:

```
angular.module('reservationsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngGrid', 'ui.bootstrap', 'reservationsControllers']);
```

And if it'll do any good, my template (pretty plain though):

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="resultsGridOptions"></div>
```

[Here's a screenshot of what I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7P8u.jpg)

Comment: Did you include the `ng-grid.css` file? Since it uses `<div>`s with classes instead of table markup, it relies on having the right CSS to render correctly.

Comment: Ah, I was linking the `.css` file, but I forgot to do `rel='stylesheet`, that fixed it!

Comment: Add the solution to your own question below and accept that answer so other people can benefit from your discovery.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, well, @GregL figured it out. I wasn't importing the `ng-grid.css` file correctly.